Control menu popup by hide/show items based on another column values
I have an interactive report region (statis ID "RequestList") with three main columns, one is configured as HTML button as below (static ID "MenuButton") and the others are current request status (static ID "CurrentStatus") and request number (static ID "RequestNumber").
another region on same page is set as list type menu popup template (static ID "ActionMenu") mapping to a defined list in shared componenet, the list is working fine without any issue but how to control the list items by hide and show based on the current request status value
HTML button code:
<button class="t-Button t-Button--icon t-Button--iconRight js-menuButton" 
id="CurrentStatus"
                data-menu="ActionMenu_menu"                
                type="button"
                 aria-expanded="false"
                data-id="#REQUEST_NUMBER#"
                data-information="#REQUEST_NUMBER#"
                data-ig-region-id="#RequestList#">
<span class="t-Icon t-Icon--right fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>


